# customising Pandoc's HTML output with CSS or a template

Tags: haskell, pandoc

I have a Happstack program that dynamically converts Markdown documents to HTML using `Text.Pandoc`:

```
import qualified Text.Pandoc as Pandoc
...
    return $ toResponse $ Pandoc.writeHtml Pandoc.def contents
```

I.e. Pandoc is returning a `Text.Blaze.Html.Html` value. (This has a `ToMessage` instance which means it can be used as a response to a request.)

How do I insert a custom CSS stylesheet into Pandoc's output? What if I want to customise the HTML e.g. by wrapping the `<body>` contents with some other elements?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When Pandoc's "standalone mode" option is enabled, it uses a template to format the output. 
The template and its substitions variables can be set in the `writerTemplate` and `writerVariables` members of `WriterOptions`.

The command line tool has a default set of template it uses. You can see the default template for a format using e.g. `pandoc -D html`.

When using the library, the default is to use an empty template.  You can get the default template programmatically using `getDefaultTemplate`.

Here's some example code:

```
import Text.Blaze.Html.Renderer.String
import Text.Pandoc

getHtmlOpts = do
    template <- either (error . show) id
        `fmap` getDefaultTemplate Nothing "html"
    return $ def
        { writerStandalone = True
        , writerTemplate = template
        , writerVariables = [
            ("css", "/path/to/style.css"),
            ("header-includes",
             "<style>p { background-color: magenta; }</style>")]
        }

main = do
    opts <- getHtmlOpts
    putStrLn $ renderHtml $ writeHtml opts $ readMarkdown def "..."
```

Comment: I was fighting the <h1 class="title"> block, since I don't want to modify my markdown files, but still want to add the <title> element properly... using `pandoc -D html > template.html` and then modifying the template to my taste (mainly adding `style="display:none"` to the `title-block-header` element, and compiling with `pandoc -s --template ./template.html --metadata title="$title" "$oldname" -o "$newname"` solved all my drama.

Answer (score 4):

You can also write your own template, call it for instance `template.html` and use the `--template template.html` option when calling pandoc from the command-line.

The documentation is at https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates, and the default template (for inspiration) is at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/master/default.html5.

Answer (score 1):

Pandoc, when run from the command line, takes some arguments that allow you to insert something into the `<head>` tag (**-H**), before content (**-B**) and after content (**-A**). I don't know about Happstack, but surely there must be a way to pass these parameters to `Pandoc.writeHtml`